# Kubernetes - execute tasks on 1 instance

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I am reaching out for ideas on the following topic. Imagine that we have 1 application. This application needs to execute an interval (cron) job. It doesn't make sense to execute however on all instances of the app. It needs to elect just one of X and execute the task, then on the next execution it would again pick one (like load-balancing).

I know that Kubernetes offers `Jobs` and `CronJob`s, but those serve only a single purpose of executing a task and then turning off, which would add more complexity to the solution.

An option is of course to have an external coordinator doing this, but I was wondering what is the Kubernetes way to handle such scenario.

Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Job pattern is what you are looking for. There are many examples in official [Kubernetes Documentation/Tasks/Run Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/)

Your need seems to match with working with a queue. In this example, as each pod is created, it picks up one unit of work from a task queue, completes it, deletes it from the queue, and exits.

1. **Start a message queue service**. In this example, we use RabbitMQ, but you could use another one. In practice you would set up a message queue service once and reuse it for many jobs.
2. **Create a queue, and fill it with messages.** Each message represents one task to be done. In this example, a message is an integer that we will do a lengthy computation on.
3. **Start a Job that works on tasks from the queue**. The Job starts several pods. Each pod takes one task from the message queue, processes it, and repeats until the end of the queue is reached.

Comment: I've read the docs, but this is not what I am looking for. A queue is an overkill, since I have the same task, repeating over time. The job is in general not a feasible option, as I don't want this container to only serve for cron and exit afterwards. It's just a regular app that should ALSO do a cron job.

Comment: Without having a shared source of messages, it can be a queue, you cannot do it. Or as you stated in the question, you will need an extra application/coordinator to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what I eventually did.

Since the recommended Kubernetes way is using the CronJobs type, I have modified my apps to be able to run in "cron mode", by specifying some config values (e.g. mode: cron/regular, cron: name of specific cron to support multiple per app).

This allows me to run the same container both as a cron on interval and as regular app for the long-running process.